# Using transloadit, how to resize two images to different sizes?

Tags: javascript, resize, transloadit

I have a form with two images on it:

[image]

I have transloadit configured so that as soon as a new image is selected, transloadit creates a thumbnail, then pushes both the thumbnail and original image to Amazon S3.

To achieve this, in my transloadit account, I've created the following template:

```
{
  "steps": {
    "thumb": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/image/resize",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150,
      "resize_strategy": "pad",
      "background": "#ffffff"
    },
    "store": {
      "use": [
        ":original",
        "thumb"
      ],
      "robot": "/s3/store",
      "key": "...",
      "secret": "...",
      "bucket": "www.mydomain.com",
      "path": "staging/${file.id}.${file.ext}"
    }
  }
}
```

And my javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var json_data = {};

    $(function() {

        // Hack to stop form submit from re-uploading files
        // https://github.com/transloadit/jquery-sdk/issues/14

        var bindTransloadit = function(form) {
          form.transloadit({
            wait: true,
            modal: true,
            triggerUploadOnFileSelection: false,
            processZeroFiles: false,
            autoSubmit: false,
            params: {
                auth: {
                    key: "..."
                },
                template_id: '...'                 
            },
            onStart: function(assembly) {
              form.find('textarea[name=transloadit]').remove();
            },
            onUpload: function(upload) {
            },
            onCancel: function() { form.unbind('submit.transloadit'); },
            onError: function(assembly) { form.unbind('submit.transloadit'); },
            onSuccess: function(assembly) { form.unbind('submit.transloadit'); },
            onResult: function(step, result)
            {

                json_data[step] = {
                    "basename": result.basename,
                    "field": result.field,
                    "name": result.name,
                    "url": result.url,
                    "ssl_url": result.ssl_url
                };

                var fld_data = '#fld_' + result.field + "_data";

                $(fld_data).val(JSON.stringify(json_data));

                if(step == "thumb")
                {
                    $(fld_data).closest('.image-select').find('.thumbnail > img').attr('src', result.url);
                }
            }
          });
        };

        $('#landing-page-form').on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() {
          var form = $(this).closest('form');
          bindTransloadit(form);
          form.trigger('submit.transloadit');
        });

    });
</script>
```

And some of my blade template/html, even though it might just confuse the issue:

```
@foreach ($fields as $name => $properties)
@if ($properties['type'] == "image")
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ $properties['label'] }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="image-select">

                <!-- Thumbnail display -->
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <?PHP if(array_key_exists('thumb', $data[$name . "_data"])) { ?>
                    <img src="<?PHP echo($data[$name . "_data"]['thumb']['url']) ?>" alt="">
                  <?PHP } ?>
                </div>

                <!-- Width/Height display -->
                <label>Width</label>: {{ $properties['width'] }} / <label>Height</label>: {{ $properties['height'] }}

                <input type="file" name="{{ $name }}" id="fld_{{ $name }}" />
                <textarea name="{{ $name }}_data" id="fld_{{ $name }}_data" class="hidden">{{ $data[$name . '_data']['json'] }}</textarea>

                @if ($properties['help_block'] != "")
                    <span class="help-block m-b-none">{{ $properties['help_block'] }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
@endif 
@endforeach
```

So far, all is good.  However, now I'd like to have transloadit resize/crop both original images to the correct size.  The primary image needs to be 300x150 pixels, and the secondary image needs to be 200x200 pixels.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured it out.  Here's how I solved it:

**1) Create resize template**

In my transloadit account, I created this template.  Most important is the resize_optimal step.  This step contains width and height values of "10", but those values will be overwritten before the step is executed.

```
{
  "steps": {
    "thumb": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/image/resize",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150,
      "resize_strategy": "pad",
      "background": "#ffffff"
    },
    "resize_optimal": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/image/resize",
      "width": 10,
      "height": 10,
      "resize_strategy": "pad",
      "background": "#ffffff"
    },
    "store": {
      "use": [
        ":original",
        "resize_optimal",
        "thumb"
      ],
      "robot": "/s3/store",
      "key": "...",
      "secret": "...",
      "bucket": "...",
      "path": "staging/${file.id}.${file.ext}"
    }
  }
}
```

**2) Add width/height to data attributes**

I modified both <input type="file"> tags to include the width and height that should be used for resizing the image as data attributes, like so:

```
<input type="file" name="primary_image" id="fld_primary_image" data-width="300" data-height="150" />
<input type="file" name="secondary_image" id="fld_secondary_image" data-width="200" data-height="200" />
```

**3) Add global resize_options array**

I added the following global array to my javascript:

```
    var resize_options = {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    };
```

**4) Override template width/height**

In my transloadit binding, I [overrode](https://transloadit.com/docs/#dynamic-assembly-instructions) the resize_optimal width and height using the values of the resize_options array:

Before:

```
            params: {
                auth: {
                    key: "..."
                },
                template_id: '...'                 
            },
```

After:

```
            params: {
                auth: {
                    key: "..."
                },
                template_id: '...',
                steps: {
                    resize_optimal: {
                        width: resize_options.width,
                        height: resize_options.height
                    }
                }                 
            },
```

**5) Populate resize_options**

In my javascript, I was already running code whenever the file input changed.  This is a great place to add code for keeping the resize_options array populated with the correct values:

Old:

```
        $('#my-form').on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() {
          var form = $(this).closest('form');
          bindTransloadit(form);
          form.trigger('submit.transloadit');
        });
```

New:

```
        $('#my-form').on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() {
          var form = $(this).closest('form');

          resize_options.width = $(this).data('width');
          resize_options.height = $(this).data('height');

          bindTransloadit(form);
          form.trigger('submit.transloadit');
        });
```

That's it!  Now both images will be resized correctly.